# Changes not having any effect out of nowhere

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was working along and out of nowhere my changes stopped applying. The code functions up until the last `logger` instruction I wrote in.
Now any change I make to the code is acting like it isn't even there. I click save and run the code, but nothing I change actually takes effect. No instances of `Logger.log("hello")` do anything, but everything else runs as written.

```
//variables for shorthand calling of each spread sheet
var ssL = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SpecsList");
var ssR = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("RequiredSpecs");

//count the number of columns to determine the max range of the spec comparison iterator
var specIteratorMax = ssL.getLastColumn() - 2; // the -2 is to ignore column A which is text and rebase the iterator variable to 0

function runHeatMap() {
  //voltage spec compare section
    Logger.log("hello");
    //retrieve the users preferred output voltage rating
    var voltReqed = ssR.getRange("A2").getValue();
    Logger.log(voltReqed);

    //retrieve the output voltage ratings of all devices
    var voltCompareData = ssL.getSheetValues(3, 2, 1, (ssL.getLastColumn() - 1)).flat();
    Logger.log(voltCompareData);
    Logger.log("hello");

    Logger.log(specIteratorMax);
    //store current iteration voltage spec and conduct comparison operations
    for (var i = 0; i <= specIteratorMax; i++) {
      var voltSpec = voltCompareData[i];
      Logger.log(voltSpec);
      if(voltSpec >= voltReqed) {
        ssL.getRange(3,i + 2).setBackground("green");
      }
      else if(voltSpec < voltReqed && voltSpec >= (voltReqed * 0.95)) {
        ssL.getRange(3,i + 2).setBackground("orange");
      }
      else {
        ssL.getRange(3,i + 2).setBackground("red");
      }
    }
    Logger.log("hello");
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you wrap your code in try{} catch(){ console.log(err); } block to see what the error is.  Or you might see the error in the Execution log

Comment: @TheWizEd did that any the behavior is unchanged

Comment: Try using Chrome in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled.

Answer (score 0):

#### It seems to run on random data

I reduced it down to this:

```
function runHeatMap() {
  var sh0 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  var sh1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var max = sh0.getLastColumn() - 2;
  var v1 = sh1.getRange("A2").getValue();
  var vs = sh0.getSheetValues(3, 2, 1, sh0.getLastColumn() - 1).flat();
  for (var i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
    var v2 = vs[i];
    if (v2 >= v1) {
      sh0.getRange(3, i + 2).setBackground("green");
    }
    else if (v2 < v1 && v2 >= (v1 * 0.95)) {
      sh0.getRange(3, i + 2).setBackground("orange");
    }
    else {
      sh0.getRange(3, i + 2).setBackground("red");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: all you've done is shorten the name of the variables, remove the logger statements, and moved the global variables to be defined inside the function...... I'm afraid that doesn't help me solve my issue. But thank you for trying.

Comment: Well I didn't have any issues to resolve.  It seems to work.

Comment: Decreasing the 0..95 to 0.50 opens up the orange range for my random data